# High "system" usage in task manager

Tags: windows-10

I have been experiencing high CPU usage by "system" and my laptop keeps buffering and pausing at regular intervals.

I found an older post with the same problem and I followed the instructions to run windows performance analyser in order to see the cause of the high CPU usage.

However I still cannot find what the problem is, here is the screenshot of the WPA window

[image: WPA window]

Comment: Do you have the NTFS "file compression" feature enabled on any files?

Comment: @user1686 I have not heard of such a feature so I would guess no